# How can I capture the response body from a curl GET?

Tags: php

My $output prints true, indicating the request was successful. How would I access the actual response body?

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_login_details');
function get_login_details(){
    $curl = curl_init();
    $auth_token = 'somerandomtoken';

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.ordercloud.io/v1/me");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bearer $auth_token'));

    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    print_r($output);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Comment: add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1)` and your body will be saved to output. currently it's echoing the body directly.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1)` and your body will be saved to `$output`.